# Trying to add a UIButton to a UIView but getting NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView addSubView:]: unrecognized

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uibutton

I'm trying to add a UIButton to a UIView but I'm getting this error at runtime.

> NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView addSubView:]:
>   unrecognized

XCode also warns me that that

> Instance method '-addSubView:' not found (return type defaults to
>   'id')

This is my code:

```
 UIView *trackPaneView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 100)] autorelease];
    [trackPaneView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

UIButton *testButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 10, 100, 30)];
    [testButton setTitle:@"AWESOME" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [trackPaneView addSubView:testButton];  //the error coming form this line
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method is `addSubview:` not addSubView:

(capitalisation error)

Comment: If this worked out, please make this question as answered @csl, thanks!

Comment: Caught me out too - didn't help that xcode highlighted it as if it had recognised the method.  It may be blinking obvious, but thanks for putting this post up, or I'd have been scratching my head for a lot longer...

Answer (score 2):

It’s `-addSubview`, not `-addSubView`. Method names are case-sensitive.

Comment: Apologies I read the other answer before I saw this. But thanks for your help @Jeff Kelley.